# Unable to install R version 4.2.0 on Ubuntu 18.04,may be did some mistakes in the process of upgrading from the older version of R version 3.6.3

Tags: r, rstudio

I already had R version 3.6.3 but for running package (DESeq2) in RStudio, it was showing to install R version 4.2.0.

In this process of installing the latest version of R. I have uninstalled both the R and rstudio. Now when I am trying to install R version 4.2.0. It showing errors. I may have done some mistakes during this whole process.

Underneath I am attaching the errors and code I have run in the terminal of Ubuntu 18.04.

```
pkd@pkd-HP-Z4-G4-Workstation:~$ sudo apt install r-base

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.2.0-1.2204.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.2.0-1.2204.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
```

More of the Error log:

```
pkd@pkd-HP-Z4-G4-Workstation:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter 
Hit:1 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                 
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15.4 kB]   
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Err:10 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ InRelease                                       
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [984 B]
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en [928 B]               
Reading package lists... Done                         
W: GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the dependencies `r-base-core` and `r-recommended` seperately prior to installing `r-base`.  Don't know if this will work, but worth a try.

Comment: Yes, i have run this command.                                                                                            (base) pkd@pkd-HP-Z4-G4-Workstation:~$ sudo apt-get install r-base


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.2.0-1.2204.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.2.0-1.2204.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: when run $ sudo apt-get update
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9                                             
W: GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ InRelease: 
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ InRelease' not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: $sudo apt-get install -y r-base-core.  The following packages have unmet dependencies: r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.35) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6 is to be installed.   Depends: libicu70 (>= 70.1-1~) but it is not installable.  Depends: libreadline8 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable. Depends: libtirpc3 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installable. Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
  Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.